# How to use Arduino decoded IR code in android studio IR transmitter program?

Tags: android-studio, arduino, infrared

I'm creating an IR remote android app with android studio. Using arduino I decoded an IR signal and the hex output is "E0E020DF". How to generate the same signal with my android app?

This is the code I'm using in android studio.

```
    ConsumerIrManager ir = (ConsumerIrManager) getSystemService(Context.CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE);
    int[] pattern = 
    int frequency = 
    ir.transmit(frequency, pattern);
```

What should I assign to 'pattern' and 'frequency' in the above code?